# Multiselect with join in SQL script

Tags: sql

I am writing this script but have this error:
The multi-part identifier "cl.user_type_id" could not be bound.

How I can fix this?

```
        SELECT cl.name AS [Name],
       col1.name AS [column],
       tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
       col2.name AS [referenced_column],
       tp.name + '(' + cast(cl.max_length AS varchar(50)) + ')' AS [DataType],
       cl.is_nullable AS [IsNullable]
FROM sys.columns cl, sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN  sys.types tp
    ON cl.user_type_id  = tp.user_type_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
WHERE cl.object_id    = Object_id('Users')
```

Comment: Note - it frequently helps if you indicate/tag the RDBS e.g., SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix old and new join syntax. Always use explicit joins instead of a comma separated table list:

```
FROM sys.columns cl
JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON ...
```

Comment: And how I can add a bool column, if  a table has reference so set true

Comment: No idea what you mean. You can ask a new question about the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the join for sys.foreign_key_columns